# Eclipse Android Error with appcompat_v7 values-14 and values-11

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, r.java-file

Im trying to see if I can get my Android App running with API 8. I've changed the build target for the project to 2.2 and I've changed the java compiler to 1.6. In problems I'm getting an error where R cant be resolved (I've checked to make sure my files don't contain import android.R) and in the console I'm getting a lot of red text that says:

> [2015-08-02 16:12:13 - my app] /home/myname/workspace/appcompat_v7/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.

I wont paste the whole console but it goes on like that for almost everything in styles_base.xml and themes_base.xml for values-v14 and values-v11

The only suggestions I have found are to change to a higher build target but I want to see if I can make my program compatible with API 8

I dont know if it's relevant but, I've searched through my project and I'm not using Holo anything either as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the minimum required SDK for a project to be API v8 and still set a higher build target. The error you quoted is related to the AppCompat library and not your project. You should have no problems setting a higher build target for the library.